# New Android virtual device does not appear as an option when running app

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, eclipse-adt

I am constantly finding myself having to recreate virtual device emulators to solve glitchy issues with Android development. Usually the process of deleting and recreating the virtual device is successful.

Today, however, after a reboot, I am able to create a new virtual device, but the newly created device(s) don't show up as an option when running the app.

Here is my process: open the Android Virtual Device Manager, choose the problematic device and delete it. Then choose New... and create a new device. When I choose 'Run As' and go to 'Run Configurations' and pick the Target tab, I have no devices to pick, even though they show up in the Virtual Device Manager. All the routine stuff, such as Refresh, have no effect.

I am running Eclipse ADT on Mac Mt. Lion. I'm sure this is another of many Eclipse bugs, but I'm unable to do much of anything now. Has anyone seen this behavior or know a solution? Thanks! Viv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are much better off testing with a physical device as most of the Android emulators are buggy at best. Since you are working in a Mac environment, configuring a virtual device is simple and should show up under run configurations (you must enable debugging on the physical device).